How to compare two times in two different timezones if they are the same moment in time?
Here's a scenario: Users are saving time only in a database as a string, e.g. 20:00. They expect something to happen every day at 8 PM. But 8 PM means a different time for different people given each lives in a different timezone, so the stored time is relative to each person.
Every hour, a server running in UTC runs a query to pull people for whom something should happen (we store their time zone separately).
The query boils down to comparing UTC server time (left side) with their relative stored time in the database (right side):
SELECT '20:00'::time = '12:00'::time AT TIME ZONE 'PST'

But there's an issue on the right side: Although '12:00'::time is sort of a timezone-less object, '12:00'::time IN TIME ZONE 'PST' returns 04:00:00-08 as if we would be converting UTC time to PST time, which is not what we want.
Alternatively, I tried comparing these as strings using:
SELECT to_char('20:00'::time AT TIME ZONE 'PST', 'HH24:MI') = '12:00'

But this throws an error function to_char(time with time zone, unknown) does not exist. It seems that to_char cannot take time with zone?
So, trying to compare times or strings, I was not able to make either approach work. Any ideas on how to make either approach work? Any alternative approaches? Or any way to force postgres to treat 12:00 as 12 AM PST?
Update: Maybe something can be put together using EXTRACT on the left side to be able to do string comparison?
SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIME '20:00'::time at time zone 'PST');
// => 12
SELECT EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM TIME '20:00'::time at time zone 'PST');
// => 0 

Pseudo code:
SELECT CONCAT(
  LEFTPAD(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIME '20:00'::time at time zone 'PST') 2 0)
  LEFTPAD(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM TIME '20:00'::time at time zone 'PST') 2 0)
) = '12:00'


time with time zone is pretty much useless. If you want to do this then you need to include the date component.

That's what I was thinking it would come to with time, but it would be so neat if that worked! It would be perfect for this use case :(

There also does not seem to be an easy way to convert time to fake timestamp in postgres. Any other way how to use 12:00 string in a column for comparisons where postgres handles timezone/DST handling?

Store the user's time as UTC

Per Postgres datetime it does come with time as time [ (p) ] with time zone. The docs go onto to say The type time with time zone is defined by the SQL standard, but the definition exhibits properties which lead to questionable usefulness., which is a polite way of saying it is basically useless.

@Bohemian Storing time in UTC will break when traveling between timezones, unfortunately.

What do you mean exactly? Can you give an example?

@bohemian It's a habit-tracking app and desired behavior is that when I set a reminder for 10:00 while on the west coast, then fly to the east coast for a few days, I still want to get the reminder at 10:00 east coast time. So, 10:00 alway relative to their current known timezone.

I updated the question with one more suggestion – maybe instead of using to_char that won't work after UTC -> PST conversion, we could use EXTRACT and concat results into a string (i.e. 12:00) which we can then easily compare with user's stored reminder time?

Okay, I figured out a solution and it was surprisingly easy in the end. See my answer below.


query boils down to comparing UTC server time (left side)

Strictly speaking you're comparing a timezone unaware type on the left to timezone aware type on the right, which results in upcasting the one on the left by assuming the default TimeZone.
It boils down to conversion rules and currently configured (default) settings:

You can use at time zone as many times as you need, each time flipping the input between with and without the time zone. In this case you probably want just one more on either side of the equation:
cast the left operand to a timezone-aware time in 'PST':
SELECT '20:00'::time at time zone 'PST' = '12:00'::time AT TIME ZONE 'PST';

or add another shift from 'PST' to 'UTC' on the right to both shift it and drop its timezone after that:
SELECT '20:00'::time = ('12:00'::time AT TIME ZONE 'PST' at time zone 'UTC')::time;

See this example:
SELECT '20:00'::time AS "C"
      ,'20:00'::time::timetz AS "D"
      ,'21:00'::time AT TIME ZONE 'PST' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS "E"
      ,('21:00'::time AT TIME ZONE 'PST' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::time AS "F"
      ,'20:00'::time = ('21:00'::time AT TIME ZONE 'PST' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::time AS "C=F"
      ,'20:00'::time::timetz = ('21:00'::time AT TIME ZONE 'PST' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::time AS "D=F"
      ,'21:00'::time AT TIME ZONE 'PST' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' = ('21:00'::time AT TIME ZONE 'PST' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::time AS "E=F";




C
D
E
F
C=F
D=F
E=F




20:00:00
20:00:00+01
20:00:00+00
20:00:00
T
T
f




When you compare time to timetz Postgres uses its type coercion/conversion rules to find a matching = operator, because there's no built-in time=timetz:
select oprleft::regtype,oprright::regtype,* 
from pg_operator 
where '{time,timetz}'::regtype[] && array[oprleft,oprright]::regtype[]
and oprname='=';




oprleft
oprright
oid
oprname
oprnamespace
oprowner
oprkind
oprcanmerge
oprcanhash
oprleft
oprright
oprresult
oprcom
oprnegate
oprcode
oprrest
oprjoin




time without time zone
time without time zone
1108
=
11
10
b
t
t
1083
1083
16
1108
1109
time_eq
eqsel
eqjoinsel


time with time zone
time with time zone
1550
=
11
10
b
t
t
1266
1266
16
1550
1551
timetz_eq
eqsel
eqjoinsel



There's only a time=time and a timetz=timetz. If you try to mix them, those rules will pick the timezone-aware variant as the preference:
select typname 
from pg_type 
where typname ilike '%time%'
  and typispreferred;




typname




timestamptz



As a result, you end up with time::timetz=timetz operation.

When the cast time::timetz happens, Postgres assumes the default TimeZone with zero regard for the context of this cast. Even though you clearly specified 'PST' on the right, the left will use whatever TimeZone is set as the default at your transaction, session, user, database or system level right now - unless overriden.

This does get the job done:
SELECT to_char(('20:00'::time AT TIME ZONE 'PST')::time, 'HH24:MI') = '12:00';

Postgres finds the interval_to_char variant of to_char() through a time::interval cast: demo at db<>fiddle
explain verbose SELECT to_char(('20:00'::time AT TIME ZONE 'PST')::time, 'HH24:MI');









Output: to_char(((('20:00:00'::time without time zone AT TIME ZONE 'PST'::text))::time without time zone)::interval, 'HH24:MI'::text)



SELECT p.pronamespace::regnamespace as "Schema",
  p.proname,
  pg_catalog.pg_get_function_result(p.oid) as "Result data type",
  pg_catalog.pg_get_function_arguments(p.oid) as "Argument data types",
  prosrc,
  pg_catalog.pg_function_is_visible(p.oid)
FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc p
WHERE p.proname ~ '^(to_char)$'
ORDER BY 1, 2, 4;




Schema
proname
Result data type
Argument data types
prosrc
pg_function_is_visible




pg_catalog
to_char
text
bigint, text
int8_to_char
t


pg_catalog
to_char
text
double precision, text
float8_to_char
t


pg_catalog
to_char
text
integer, text
int4_to_char
t


pg_catalog
to_char
text
interval, text
interval_to_char
t


pg_catalog
to_char
text
numeric, text
numeric_to_char
t


pg_catalog
to_char
text
real, text
float4_to_char
t


pg_catalog
to_char
text
timestamp without time zone, text
timestamp_to_char
t


pg_catalog
to_char
text
timestamp with time zone, text
timestamptz_to_char
t



However, that's a lot of steps (time::timetz::time::interval::text) just to end up at a slightly less efficient text=text comparison while the type and timezone alignment from point 1. gives you a native, numerical time=time after doing just time::timetz::time.
The demo shows how much of a difference that could amount to - it ain't much, but its there if you're interested.



I'm on Heroku's PostgreSQL 13 currently.

Thanks for the detailed explanation. All that reasoning makes sense. However, did you try to run the queries in point 1? The problem is that '12:00'::time AT TIME ZONE 'PST' at time zone 'UTC'is again 12:00:00+00 which is not equal to '20:00'::time or 20:00::time AT TIME ZONE 'PST'. It seems to be impossible to construct a query SELECT left = right // => true while using 20:00 on one side and 12:00 on the other as the db will always treat both as UTC, and that's the problem here.

The best case scenario you end up with SELECT 12:00:00-08 = 12:00:00+00 or vice-versa, which is always false and that's the issue I'm raising.

@MichalKrejčí I did. The examples were meant to just show the addition of one more at time zone, either on the left or on the right to avoid the quiet ::timetz cast that silently adds your TimeZone leading to the mismatch. That being said, that second example was missing a downcast to ::time on the right or should've included another at time zone 'UTC' on the left. I fixed that now and added more demos and examples.

Wow, thank you so much for a very detailed answer. I think it is great you posted this and I'm sure many people find this post and will help them in the future. I came up with the solution in the meantime too, but I will mark your post as the answer simply because of the amount of insight in it. Thanks!

Okay, I think I got it. Time zone can be stripped easily after timezone conversation back into time without time zone for string comparison:
SELECT to_char(('20:00'::time AT TIME ZONE 'PST')::time, 'HH24:MI') = '12:00';

